# Remove item by text from QStandardItemModel in QT

Tags: qt, pyqt

How can I remove an item with text "something" from a `QStandardItemModel` that filled with `QStandardItem` items and shown in a `QListView` in `pyqt`.
I made my `QStandardItemModel` like code shown below:

```
item = QtGui.QStandardItem("something")
QStandardItemModel.appendRow(item)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will first need to [find the items](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#findItems) with the matching text, and then [remove them](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeRow) from the model:

```
model = listview.model()
for item in model.findItems('something'):
    model.removeRow(item.row())
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution given only works when findItems returns a single item.
Otherwise the first call to removeRow will invalidate the next items...

Comment: Or maybe it's because I'm working with a QTreeView and passing the Qt::MatchRecursive flag to findItems...